# How do I call a reusable workflow in github actions and pass a value to its predefined input param

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions, workflow

My workflow:

```
name: test

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      env:
        description: 'Test'
        default: 'stage'
        required: true
        type: string
```

From docs [reusable workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows):

```
jobs:
  call-workflow-passing-data:
    uses: octo-org/example-repo/.github/workflows/reusable-workflow.yml@main
    with:
      config-path: .github/labeler.yml
    secrets:
      envPAT: ${{ secrets.envPAT }}
```

But I dont understand where do I pass my "env" input variable when i call the workflow in a different workflow? would it be considered a secret? So I just gotta do

```
        secrets:
           env: "someEnv"
```

Is it like this?

Or should I modify this:

```
    with:
      config-path: .github/labeler.yml
```

To this:

```
    with:
      env: "abc"
```

Comment: You configured the workflow call using `inputs`, and not `secrets`, so you need to use the syntax `with`: `with: env: "abc"`

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the link you shared, there are two different types of inputs you can customize in reusable workflows: The `inputs` field, and the `secrets` field.

**Example with the `inputs` field:**

```
name: example1

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      env:
        description: 'Test'
        default: 'stage'
        required: true
        type: string
```

This workflow will be called by using:

```
jobs:
  example1:
    uses: <ORG>/<REPO>/.github/workflows/reusable-workflow.yml@main
    with:
      env: 'ENV_VALUE'
```

---

**Example with the `secrets` field:**

```
name: example2

on:
  workflow_call:
    secrets:
      env:
        description: 'Test'
        required: true
```

This workflow will be called by using:

```
jobs:
  example2:
    uses: <ORG>/<REPO>/.github/workflows/reusable-workflow.yml@main
    secrets:
      env: ${{ secrets.SECRET_NAME }}
```

---

**Example with both `inputs` and `secrets` field:**

```
name: example3

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      env:
        description: 'Test'
        default: 'stage'
        required: true
        type: string
    secrets:
      env:
        description: 'Test'
        required: true
```

This workflow will be called by using:

```
jobs:
  example3:
    uses: <ORG>/<REPO>/.github/workflows/reusable-workflow.yml@main
    with:
      env: 'ENV_VALUE'
    secrets:
      env: ${{ secrets.SECRET_NAME }}
```